# codeigniter model does not return results as defined on limt

Tags: database, codeigniter-3

this is my model

```
function get_one_news($limit = 2, $offset = null) {

            if ($limit) {

                $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            }

            $this->db->order_by('news.added_on', 'desc');

            return $this->db->get('news');


        }
```

and in my controller i had assign it like

```
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_one_news();
```

in my view i had implement it like

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <!-- artigo em destaque -->
            <?php if ($news->num_rows()):?>
            <?php foreach ($news->result() as $n):?>
            <?php if ($n->cat_id == 17):?>
            <div class="featured-article">
                <a href="#">
                <?php if ($n->image != ''): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$n->image);?>" alt="" class="thumb">
                <?php endif;?>
                </a>
                <div class="block-title">
                    <h4><?php echo $n->title = word_limiter($n->title, 7);?></h4>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.featured-article -->
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
```

this query 
gives me result but if i put limit 3 it gives 2 if i put 2 it gives 1  and if i put 1 it wont give any result why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you echo $news->num_rows()? I suspect it might have something to do with:

```
<?php if ($n->cat_id == 17):?>
```

Are you getting the same number of rows as your limit but it is filtering out the most recent one because it isn't cat_id == 17?